# Is it possible to filter Frequencies with AKEqualizerFilter?

Tags: swift, audiokit

I use **`AKEqualizerFilter`** from **`amazing AudioKit framework`** in my project and everything works perfectly, except decrease of frequencies. On `AudioKit GitHub-website` is shown that Gain-reduction between *-100 and 100* is possible, but when i go below 0, the frequencies are again louder.

How can I reduce gain *below 0!* of chosen frequencies with `AKEqualiserFilter`?

This is from `AKEqualizerFilter` branch:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Effects/Filters/Equalizer%20Filter/AKEqualizerFilter.swift

```
/// A 2nd order tunable equalization filter that provides a peak/notch filter
/// for building parametric/graphic equalizers. With gain above 1, there will be
/// a peak at the center frequency with a width dependent on bandwidth. If gain
/// is less than 1, a notch is formed around the center frequency.
///


/// Lower and upper bounds for Gain
    public static let gainRange = -100.0 ... 100.

My Code:

        myEqualiserFilter1 = AKEqualizerFilter(myCompressor)
        myEqualiserFilter1.rampDuration = 0.3
        myEqualiserFilter1.centerFrequency = 50 
        myEqualiserFilter1.bandwidth = 50 
        kickEqualiserFilter1.gain = 0.0


//Slider action: 
conductor.kickEqualiserFilter1.gain = Double(sender.value)
```

I would like to filter/reduce Frequencies from Audio Samples and I hope it is possible with AudioKit.

Comment: I'll check on this.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka  Thank you for your response and thank you for Audiokit!! My app should go online in the next few days and I hope we will find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The range is incorrect in AudioKit, it should be a non-negative number. I've changed it on the develop branch.

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/b811ac146e95d3666695dba59c6cd87593223066

A zero gain is the most reduction for that bandwidth.

Comment: Oh, that’s a pity. Is there any other way to reduce frequencies? Anyway thank you for the clarification. AKEqualiserFilter was my hope.